# How to count occurences of a pointer to a specific object in different vector arrays

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have defined a class `node`.
An `element` class consist  of four pointer to different nodes. A node pointer can be shared between elements.
`nodes` and `elements` are vector arrays of `node` and `element` objects.

```
 std::vector<node> nodes;
 std::vector<element>elements; //Each element consist of four node pointer.
```

pointer to `node`object can be shared by different `element` object, i.e different `element` objects may contain same pointer to `node` object. How can I identify the `element` objects from the vector array of elements  if there is/are `node`objects in the element which are not shared by more than two elements.

Example:
Id's of `node` objects are 1,2,3,4,5 and 6.
`element` elem1 contains  nodes of Id's 1,2,3,4 and `element` elem2 contain nodes of Id's 3,4,5,6. Then both elements satisfy the above criteria.

EDIT 1:
I prefer solutions which doesn't shuffle/change `vector elements`. A new vector of elements has to be created with the identified `element` objects

EDIT 2:
My program is intended to parse an input file of large data of nodes and element. Memory and efficiency is important.

Comment: What do you want to do with `elem1` and `elem2` once you have identified them? Run some function on them? Store them in a new container? Shuffle them all to the front of the `elements` container? There are algorithms in `<algorithm>` to help you achieve these, but I can't help you pick one without knowing really what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'll iterate through vector of separated out `element` objects and run some functions

Comment: That sounds like your idea of how to do it, not what you *actually* want to do. Do you *need* them in a new container? Or do you only *need* to call a function on them, but  you assumed that meant you needed them in a new container?

Comment: Take a look at [std::shared_ptr::use_count](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count) if you need to count references.

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych I don't think lifetime is an issue here; unnecessary shared ownership would just confuse things.

Comment: @BoBTFish I just suggested one of the ways to count references to objects because OP states in his question about checking criteria `objects which are not shared by more than two elements.`

Comment: @BoBTFish, I don't actually need them in a new container but I prefer it.

Comment: The naive solution should be obvious, so what you need to tell us are the requirements of the algorithm. Are the vectors very large? Is memory important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the first step you need to do is to identify how many unique node pointers are present. You can parse the `elements`vector and store all the `node` pointers in a `map` which looks like this

```
map<node*, std::list<element> > node_to_element
```

Each entry in this map will store the list of `element`objects which refer to a `node` pointer

Next, you need to iterate this map and find out those node pointers which have list size <= 2.

Once you have those entries, you have the `element` objects which refer to not more than 2 `node` pointers

**EDIT**

As @sameerkn & @0x499602D2 pointed out, the map can be modified to look like this

```
map <node *, std::vector<int> > node_to_element_indexes
```

where `std::vector<int>` may be used to store the index of element objects in `std::vector<element> elements` which refer to the `node *`

Comment: `map<node*,  std::list<int>> node_to_element;`. Instead of `std::list<element>`,   `std::list<int>` can be used which will store index of `std::vector<element> elements;`

Comment: @Rishi,  Thanks for giving insight

Comment: Why did you decide to use a linked list rather than a vector?

Comment: `vector` can be used. I had just posted an example. I like @sameerkn suggestion mentioned in the comments above. The suggestion can be reformed by using a `std::vector<int>` which will store index of `std::vector<element> elements`